# What is the connection between vāstu śāstra and the varṇa system?

Tags: caste-system, varna, vastu-shastra

I heard that vāstu śāstra is tightly linked to the varṇa (caste) system. E.g., a brāhmaṇa should construct a house on white land, the soil should smell like a lotus, taste very sweet, facing north, etc. Whereas kṣatriya should look for land that has red soil, should smell and taste like blood, etc. A śūdra should find land facing west, the soil should taste bitter, look very dark in color, so on.

Are there references to various varṇas in vāstu śāstra?

Comment: Brihat Samhita  is mentioning about  that. But it is not a text specifically related to vastu-Shastra.We will need to look for the answer in core   texts.- https://archive.org/stream/Brihatsamhita/brihatsamhita#page/n467/mode/2up

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Good find. You should post it as an answer. From what I heard there isn't a single 'core text' (pramāṇa) for vāstu śāstra.

Comment: -Yes , thanks. But honestly the verse ls kind a   strange verse ,  And doesn't look  fine to me from any of the angle. Actually this book is not a dharmik kind of scripture but a general book  .Nobody will accept this kind of logic . So it will be a bit difficult . May be we should try to find more about this from other vastu shastra books.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you heard definitely has a scriptural basis. [This Matsya Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/matsya/bookview.php?chapnum=24) chapter mentions the various types of soils suitable for various Varna people to build their houses on:

> As regards the DAYS, all the days of a week are good, except Sundays
>   and Tuesdays. In regard to YOGAS, construction should not start on the
>   following yogas viz. Vyaaghat, Shula, Vyatipaat, Atiganda, Vishkambha,
>   Ganda, Parigha and Vajra. Following MUHURTAS are stated to be ideal
>   for contstruction viz. Sweta, Maitra, Maahendra, Gaandhawa, Abhijit,
>   Rouhini, Vairaja, and Savitri. To decide on the SHUBHA LAGNA, the
>   activity of construction should be commenced when the Chandra bala as
>   also Suryabala would be equally positve. The most important activities
>   apart, Stambharohana or the hoisting of the Pillar should be taken up
>   first; similarly the procedures should be the same as in respect of
>   the costruction of Praasaads, wells and such mini water bodies. **SOIL
>   TEST would be the foremost activity before the actual construction is
>   taken up. Sweta (White), Lal (Red), Peeta (yellowish) and kaala
>   (black) may be the ideal soils for the Four Varnas of Brahmana,
>   Kshatriya, Vaisya and Shudra respectively. Taste-wise, the soil may be
>   sweetish for Brahmanas, sour for Kshatriyas, tiktha or bitter for
>   Vaishyas and Kasaili/ Kashaya / Pungent for Shudras**. As a part of
>   the soil quality test, saplings are to be planted and the best soil
>   quality would yield the growth over three nights; medium growth over
>   five nights and minimal growth over a week. The best soil obviously
>   would give out the quickest yield

Update:

The Tantra SAra book (on pp 535) quotes some Gautamiya Tantram's verses that are related to the topic. Here are the verses:

> Gautamiye--- tatrApi prathamam bhuminirnayah|
>
> Bhumeh parigraham kuryAdyAvatAyatanam bhaveth |
>  ShuklamritasnA tu
>   yA bhumirbrAhmi sA parikirtitA |
>  Kshatriya raktamridu
>   bhumirharidvaishyA prakirtitA |
>  KrishnA bhumirbhavet shudrA
>   chaturdha bhuh prakirtita |
>  BrAhmi sarvArthasiddhi syAt kshatriyA
>   rAjyadA matA |
>  DhanadhAnyakAri vaishyA shudrA tu ninditA bhaveh |
>
> The ground which has white colored soil is called BrAhmi Bhumi, the
>   one with red colored soil is called KshatriyA, the one with yellow
>   colored soil is Vaishya and the one with black colored soil is called
>   the Shudra Bhumi. The BrAhmi Bhumi fulfills all wishes, the KsatriyA
>   is the giver of kingdom, the Vaishya Bhumi is the bestower of wealth
>   but the Shudra Bhumi is censured.